# Jumping to the next record with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails application that I want to be able to jump to the next page or go back a page (with arrow buttons) which appear next to the picture (which is a comic image).  However, I can not find out how to do this.  My controller is simple with:

```
 @page = Page.find(params[:id])
```

Page belongs to *book* and has that relationship established.  I can not simply increment the page id by one because that may result giving it a page from a completly diffrent book.  Any help is great.

The image below is what I basically what I want to do.

[image: Click N' Slide Project]

Comment: You mean like paginate over a collection of pages that are from the same book?

Comment: @Devin M Yes very similar to that.  However it seems to me will_paginate places it like <previous 1 2 3 next> but I want the arrows where you can see them in pink in the picture.

Comment: Thats a style thing, you should be able to place and generate those links wherever you want. Let me take a look at will_paginate.

Comment: @Devin M I was hoping for a solution that would not require me to use absolute positioning over a table.

Comment: I mean render the link where you want to place it, if you can place the images there then why not just make them image links. All the link generator is doing is incrementing or decrementing the page number in the url params, should be simple enough to do.

Comment: @Devin M, not necessarily.  Since there is multiple books with multiple files it means the pages are not always sequential.  So a path could be /books/1/pages/4 then /books/1/pages/12 while books/2/pages/5 book 2 would have the page id of 5.

Comment: You wont be paginating by id, you would be paginating by collection. Use will paginate, set the number of items to one and call will paginate on `Book.pages` right? Thats a collection that just shows the pages belonging to that book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page model you can add the following instance methods:

```
def next_page
  self.book.pages.where('id > ?', self.id).order('id').first
end

def previous_page
  self.book.pages.where('id < ?', self.id).order('id desc').first
end
```

With these methods you can do:

```
@page.next_page
```

and:

```
@page.previous_page
```

Comment: I am getting this error `undefined method `pages' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Do you have `:belongs_to book` in your `Page` model? Does the page you are testing this for belong to a book?? Not sure why you are getting this error. If you update the question with your Page and Book models, I may be able to help you.

Comment: page.rb has `belongs_to :book` and book.rb has `has_many :pages` the pages table has a field of book_id for a foreign key.

Comment: And every record in your pages table has a book_id that also exists in the books table? Can you add your models to the question? The error message means that `self.book` is somehow `nil`...

Comment: I think I found the problem...It appears book_id is not getting populated.  I am checking into it now.

Comment: Glad it works. This answer assumes that the id of page 1 is smaller than the id of page 2 of the same book. You may want to add some checks for `nil` values too. Good luck.